# How do I export TFRecord with data in Intel CVAT?

Tags: computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, opencv3.0, gcp-ai-platform-training

I've annotated roughly 15 mins of video with intel's CVAT. - https://github.com/opencv/cvat

When exporting to TFRecord, the file is only about 4mb (should be closer to 200mb at least), and doesn't appear to actually contain any image data. How can I export a TF Record with the image data along with the annotation data?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, which is what brought me to your question. It appears that CVAT only exports annotation data and you're responsible for extracting the image data. At least that's what I gather from my experiments with it and the lack of information in the documentation regarding exporting image data pulled from video. As far as I can tell there is enough to go by if you have the frame numbers and the video file -- just open the video and extract the frames and save those into the TFRecord as the image data. WCGW, right? Good luck! Please post code here if you work this out.

Comment: BTW if you're a Python programmer there is some simple OpenCV code for getting frames from a video here: https://gist.github.com/keithweaver/70df4922fec74ea87405b83840b45d57. It should be reasonably straight-forward to push this data into the TFRecord, assuming you know which frame goes with which annotation.

Comment: I ended up using ffmpeg to split, export to Coco json, replace frame numbers with file paths, then converting to tfrecord

Comment: It isn't especially well-documented, but you can apparently get the frame data out of CVAT's REST API.  Sending a request to the endpoint `/api/v1/tasks/<task_id>/frames/<frame_ndx>` returns the image data for the frame.  You can get the number of frames in each task from the `start_frame` and `stop_frame` keys in the response to `/api/v1/tasks/<task_id>`.  You'd have to combine the annotations and images on your own, though.  I can post an answer with code if that would be helpful (once I figure it out...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 12/1/2019 - This is not currently supported in intel CVAT.

I was able to achieve my goal, and create tfrecords containing both annotation data and image data by using a combination of `ffmpeg` to split my original `.mov` into frames and [create_pascal_tf_record.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pascal_tf_record.py) to generate the tfrecord.